# Google Plugin for Eclipse Can't Log In to Google

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Google Plugin for Eclipse does does allow me to sign in.  I click to greyed out sign in button, enter my credentials, and I get an error (below).  I'm using Eclipse 4.3 with Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 version 3.4.2.

Here is the error log from Eclipse:

```
Could not sign in. Make sure that you entered the correct verification code.

org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3654e7a4; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._throwInvalidSpace(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._skipWSOrEnd(Utf8StreamParser.java:2322)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:444)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonParser.nextToken(JacksonParser.java:55)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.startParsing(JsonParser.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:372)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:347)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:385)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.GoogleLogin.logIn(GoogleLogin.java:321)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.login.ui.LoginTrimContribution$1.mouseUp(LoginTrimContribution.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)

eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/ -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/ -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not having any problems and it looks like we have similar versions of everything ... i just did an update

java version "1.7.0_25"java version "1.7.0_25"
Google App Engie Java SDK 1.8.6 
Google plugin for eclipse 4.3 version 3.4.2.v2011310081834-rel-r43
uname -a
Linux archdd 3.11.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Oct 18 23:22:36 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Hmm.  This is very encouraging.  I see I'm having problems coming from org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException.  I didn't know that jackson was even in the JDK.  It is in my project build path, but the issue exists even when I close that project.  Do you have jackson on your system, and what version is it?  Thank you so much!

Comment: More to the point, after googling, it looks like the JSON is expecting gzipped data, and jackson can't unpack the gzip it expects.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091524/how-to-parse-an-application-json-object-into-a-string  I don't really get why this would be happening to me and not you, so I'll just reinstall everything.

Comment: there have been other occasions in the past that i have had upgrade issues and ended up starting my installation from scratch as well. glad that you are up and running again

Comment: i also have a bug of sorts, well, an annoyance, when i deploy to appengine i get error message: An internal error occurred during: "Deploying dxxxxxxx.com to Google".
java.lang.NullPointerException. but it actually seems to deploy, i just dont know what this error could be or if its affecting me at all

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the GPE plugin, same version, fixed the problem temporarily, but returned after a while.   This is clearly a bug.

Comment: Reinstalled Kepler from scratch, keeping things minimal, and all works well again.  I must have crufted up my eclipse somehow. Ias able to sign in and deploy.